# node.js xml xsd validation

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, xsd

So can I use XSD validation in Node.js? I tried search but had not got result. Please help.

I now that I can use xmllint but I wanr use some module.

So I saw same quaestion one year old but I thought maybe some changed for year.